# How to set the value for dropdown box?

Tags: php, codeigniter, dropdownbox

i want to display the value for all the textbox with the help of this code

```
value="<?php `if(!empty($result) && !empty($result['part'])){ echo $result['part']; } ?>">
```

Where part is the name of the database field...same thing i have to display for dropdown box how can i do this..In dropdown box the options are displayed with the help of another table

```
<select class="bootstrap-select show-tick" data-size="5" data-live-search="true" data-width="100%" name="TName1" required>
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select Sub Account Name</option>
    <?php foreach ($accName as $row ): ?>
    <option value="<?=$row['id']?>" <?php echo set_select('accName', $row['id']); ?>>
        <?=$row['accName']?>
    </option>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</select>
```

where accName is the name stored in another table..i want to display the name here..but it had to be stored as code(predefined integer value) in my database field...How can i did this..??

Comment: What is the exact problem here? How does the generated code look like?

Comment: i have two acctname for that code and id value are same for ex:accname is xxxx then the code value and id value is 1..if the user click on xxxx then the value have to be stored as 1 in code database field

Comment: Please add such explanation to the question itself. Additionally, what is the problem in using the ID as the value and submit it to the backend?

Comment: don't no what you exactly want but if you want to get textarea field value then.
<textarea name="" type="text" value=""><?php echo $row['accName'];?></textarea>

Answer (score 2):

Value for drop down is set different way than that of text box or text area.

Drop down has options and one of its options (multiple in case it is a multiple dropdown) is set to be selected one.

So, `<option>` syntax:

`<option value="value">Text</option>`

If we want to make an option selected, use `selected' attribute of``

`<option value="value" selected="selected">Text</option>`

So, in your case, solution would be:

1) Take value from database.

2) In the options loop, compare database value with current iteration `<option>` value.

3) If any of options' values are matching, use `selected` attribute of `<option>`

```
<select class="bootstrap-select show-tick" data-size="5" data-live-search="true" data-width="100%" name="TName1" required>
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select Sub Account Name</option>
    <?php foreach ($accName as $row ):
    $selected = ($dbValueForDropDown == $row['id']) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
    ?> 
    <option value="<?=$row['id']?>" <?php echo set_select('accName', $row['id']); ?> <?php echo $selected;?>><?=$row['accName']?></option> 
    <?php endforeach ?>         
</select>
```

Comment: I have previous selected result in this field value="<?php `if(!empty($result) && !empty($result['code'])){ echo $result['code']; } ?>"> for code i have name in another table where if the code and id value is matched then it have to display the account name

Comment: @dhara, thanks for the comment. Please replace the variable $dbValueForDropDown with database value. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

you should bring id and name of the accounts in the same results set by join in the query you send to the database and then run on the results and put the id in the value and the name in the display

Comment: in mysql, for example - "select A.id, N.name from Accounts A inner join Accounts_names N on A.id = N.id". that assumes Accounts  is the accounts  table and Accounts_names is the table holds the accounts names.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <select class="bootstrap-select show-tick" data-size="5" data-live-search="true" data-width="100%" name="TName" required placeholder="select account name">
<option value="" disabled selected>Select Account Name</option>
<?php foreach ($accName as $row ): 
$selected = '';
if($row['id'] == $result['code']){
$selected = 'selected = selected';
}
?> 
<option <?php echo $selected; ?> value="<?=$row['id']?>" <?php echo set_select('accName', $row['id']); ?>> 
<?=$row['accName']?></option> 

<?php endforeach ?> 
</select>
```